# CRM 2011 get the attribute names of empty attributes of an entity

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am currently working on a little crm 2011 Plugin which should update all assoiated contacts when an accounts data is changed. 
So the plugin works on the Update Message in the Post-Operation stage.

It is working nearly as I would like it to, but there is one small problem.
In the case a user opens up an account and changes the data of this account, when he fills out a previously empty field these changes will not be transfered to all contacts.

My problem in this case is, since I check if the changed attribute names (keys in the AttributeCollection) are also available on the contacts, that when a empty field got filled out, the affected contacts will not have a key value pair I could check if the key is presenent.

e.g. an account has no value for the field "street_1", afterwards this field gets a value from a user. Now every contact, which belongs to this account, should be updated and get this value copied into the contact field "street_1"
but since in the contact, "street_1" was empty, the contacts I retrive which belong to the account don`t have a "street_1" attribute key.

so my question is, how do I get all attribute names of an entity, in this case contact, even when the attribute have no value.

PS: I would like to bypass, using the early bound class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PreImage in your plugin, in this way you can check the previous values.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_preandpost

Comment: Since he is asking about fields on a related entity (contact) how does the PreImage (account) help?

Comment: yeah, probably I read the question too fast, however if he retrieves the related contacts with a ColumnSet(true) and the field is not in the collection means that the field is empty

Comment: Right, I think the answer is that if his query is returning the field and it is not in the collection he should just add the new value to the collection.

Comment: I need the key to check if this value should even be added to the contact. since I want to update the changes made in an account to all associated contacts.